# Sqoop Import Fails “No Space Left on Device”

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

Sqoop unable to import data into hadoop thorwing error as " No Space Left on Device" on random table. We have plenty of space on both HDFS and Local FS. Not sure why, Please let me know how to fix it.

```
SELECT ALTR_DESC WHERE 1=1 WITH UR 2017-03-29 00:32:27 ERROR 
SqoopThread:165 - Error occurred while importing data 
HALS.CLOUD_AESC java.lang.RuntimeException:     
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /apps/data/cloud.log 170329.003227.HALSDBP3.1694.TBA_ALTR_DESC.log (No space left on device) at     
com.apache.sqoop.log.LogWriter.close(LogWriter.java:137) at     
com.apache.sqoop.log.LogWriter.flush(LogWriter.java:155) at 
com.apche.sqoop.log.LogWriter.write(LogWriter.java:41) at 
com.apache.sqoop.service.SqoopThread.run(SqoopThread.java:100) at      
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /apps/data/cloud.log/170329.003227.HALSDBP3.1694.TBA_ALTR_DESC.log (No space left on device) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at 
java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:221) at 
java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:142) at 
java.io.FileWriter.(FileWriter.java:78) at 
com.apache.sqoop.log.LogWriter.close(LogWriter.java:127)
```

Comment: Output of  `df -h /apps`

Answer (score 2):

It means that you don't have enough storage space in one (or more) of your cluster's node(s). Check the Web UI of HDFS to see each datanode and the remaining space as the job is executed.

This space might be freed after you run the job, so you may need to check it while the job is running. If there is not enough time to do this (i.e., the job is fast), then you could also check the datanode logs on each datanode to identify which one is failing to store data.

I am not familiar with sqoop, but a standard ways to solve this is to use compression and another way could be to reduce the replication factor from 3 to 2, or even 1 (but this has an impact on fault tolerance and data locality). However, the first thing is to identify *when* and *why* this is happening.

Comment: we have plenty of space in hdfs nearly 50%

Comment: Check the total free disk space available on *every* cluster node. One node may run out of disk, which could mean that it gets all the heavy load. How big are the tables (all together) and how much space do you have? What is the replication factor?